# Can use EAGER LOADING Instead of JOINS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, eager-loading

I want to find out is any way that can use EAGER LOADING instead of JOINS for The below Code Section?
For all JOINS statments I want to Know That.
The relations are clear, but if you had question about Relations please ask

```
var Books = (from b in _context.Books

                         //Join Publisher VS Books
                          join p in _context.Publishers on b.PublisherID equals p.PublisherID

                         //Join Authors VS Books
                         join u in _context.Author_Books on b.BookID equals u.BookID
                         join a in _context.Authors on u.AuthorID equals a.AuthorID

                         //Full Outer Join Translators VS Books
                         join bt in _context.Book_Translators on b.BookID equals bt.BookID into btx
                         from bts in btx.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join t in _context.Translators on bts.TranslatorID equals t.TranslatorID into ftx
                         from ft in ftx.DefaultIfEmpty()

                         //Full Outer Join Categories VS Books
                         join cb in _context.Book_Categories on b.BookID equals cb.BookID into fcbx
                         from fcb in fcbx.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join c in _context.Categories on fcb.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID into fcx
                         from fc in fcx.DefaultIfEmpty()

                         //Join Languages VS Books
                         join l in _context.Languages on b.LanguageID equals l.LanguageID

                          where b.Delete != true && b.Title.Contains(Title.TrimStart().TrimEnd())
                         && b.ISBN.Contains(ISBN.TrimStart().TrimEnd())
                         && b.Language.LanguageName.Contains(Language.TrimStart().TrimEnd())
                         && b.Publisher.PublisherName.Contains(Publisher.TrimStart().TrimEnd())
                         select new 
                          { 
                              b.BookID,
                              b.Title,
                              b.ISBN,
                              b.Price,
                              b.PublishDate,
                              b.IsPublish,
                              p.PublisherName,
                              Author= a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName,
                              b.Stock,

                             TranslatorFullName = bts != null ? ft.Name + " " + ft.Family : "",
                             //Category = fcb != null ? fc.CategoryName : "",
                             Category = fc.CategoryName,
                             l.LanguageName,


                         }).Where(a=>a.Author.Contains(Author) && a.TranslatorFullName.Contains(Translator) && a.Category.Contains(Category)) 
                         .GroupBy(b=>b.BookID)
                         .Select(g => new { BookID = g.Key, BookGroups = g });
```

Comment: why aren't you using a stored procedure for this amount of joins?

Comment: I am working on Store Procedure and View recently. but my question is different